# Eclipse - Change Console background color

Tags: java, eclipse, colors, background

I applied a theme for eclipse, where the Console's background color is to dark.

If I want to change it by right clicking on the Console -> preferences -> background color the new Color doesnt get applied. Is there a way to apply a new BG Color even when using a theme?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a similar problem with luna. Didn't work with the dark 'theme' and similar dark 'color and font theme' - had to reset to classic under main preferences. Then right clicking from within the console does change to the selected colour. 
Maybe related to this recurring [bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=103907) in eclipse.

Comment: Ahhh thank you it worked for me now. I set the theme back to the default one, changed the Console's color and applied my custom theme again

Comment: Aurus, glad it helped - feel free to accept this as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I got the mentioned bug too but after right clicking it was too dark for me since the text colour is black.

The settings for the console background colour are located here:

Eclipse:

`Window` -> `Preferences`

Preferences:

-> `C/C++` -> `Build` -> `Console`

(probably a similar path applies to Java too)

Console:

-> `Background color`

---

There are also two other console background settings in: Preferences: -> `C/C++` -> `Debug` -> `GDB` -> `Console` and in `Run/Debug` -> `Console`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you made sure that you clicked the actual 'Apply' button?

If so, try if you can change it from the the tab window and then pick Prefrences.

Window -->Preferences

Hopefully this helps you.

Comment: Well if I change it like that it works until i make a click on the console window. After that it changes back to the themes one. :/

Answer (score 0):

go to ->preferences->type:console-> click on "console" ->click on "Background color"

Answer (score 0):

Try Windows -> Preferences -> Appearance -> Colors and Fonts -> expand folder based on your perspective.

Example: In my eclipse currently opened in debugger perspective and need to change font colors in console.

[Change Font colors in Eclipse Console ( Debug Perspective)]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/m73PI.png